# Get value from JSON object in Prolog

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I have two questions.

- How can I access the values in a JSON data structure in Prolog?
- How can I yield a list of solutions from a predicate as JSON?

My Code:

```
handle(Request) :-
   format(user_output,"I'm here~n",[]),
   http_read_json(Request, DictIn,[json_object(term)]),
   %beat(DictIn.name,DictIn.move,X),
   %get list of solution of beat in to JSON and keep it in DictOut
   reply_json(DictOut).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using SWI Prolog. Your code suggests that you want to convert JSON to SWI Prolog dicts. So you need to change

`http_read_json(Request, DictIn, [json_object(term)])`

to

`http_read_json(Request, DictIn, [json_object(dict)])`,

or you can just use `http_read_json_dict/2`. Note that `Request` must be a PUT or POST request or else these predicates will throw a `domain_error(Type, Term)`.

You can print out `DictIn` to take a look at what fields you want to extract.

For the response use `reply_json_dict/{1, 2}`.